# Correct format for JSON file being accessed via getJSON()?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

**.json file**

```
{"object_name":
    [
        {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
        {"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}
    ]
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_id li a").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://path/to/json.json", function(my_results){  
            console.log(my_results.object_name[0].key2);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I was expecting that this would output:

The value of `key2`, in the first object, in the `object_name` array.

But it's not outputting anything to the console.

What is incorrect in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your JSON is missing a comma between the two rows. Try running it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) to check it.

Comment: good lord, i have been troubleshooting that for 12 hours.  can accept answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
{"object_name":
[
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a comma(,) in your object_name

For JSon validators you can visit this [link](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{"object_name":
    [
        {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
        {"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}
    ]
}
```